# How are preferences related to relative prices?

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, preferences

For instance, across regions of a country or between countries.

Is that different preferences for food lead to distinct relative prices in different regions or countries? Or is it the other way around: distinct relative prices lead to differences in preferences?

Comment: clearly it is both.

Comment: @BB King. Can you explain then.